# How can I override the button display home

Tags: java, android

By default the button(setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled), returns the parent activity, how would I change it? For example: I need to back to a Intent

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb_dados);
    toolbar.setTitle("Adicione uma descrição");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Do you want to go to another activity when you click the arrow on the toolbar?

Comment: No, if I want to go to another acitivity, I know I could do this through the AndroidManifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `onOptionsItemSelected` method and perform any other function if you want

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "back Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this....

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case android.R.id.home:

        // your intent code here.

                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using custom toolbar so you can easily use custom toolbar like this

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back_arrow);// use your back arrow image
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));//call which activity you want in back press
            finish();
        }
    });
```